# Creating a DataFrame from a list and enforce dtype results in TypeError or ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, windows, dataframe, integer

Let's say I have a list of numbers stored as string and want to put it in a DataFrame *while setting the dtype*. This is on Python 3.9 with pandas 1.3.5.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
# '1.3.5'

test = ['15731245100']

df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=["id"], dtype="float64")
# works
```

However, for integer types, this fails and it is beyond my understanding why. With pandas 1.1.5 on Python 3.6 I did *not* have this problem.

A. For "int64" conversion I get a ValueError:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=["id"], dtype="int64")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-3c90fbd765c6>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=["id"], dtype="int64")
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 711, in __init__
    mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 313, in ndarray_to_mgr
    values = sanitize_array(
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 545, in sanitize_array
    subarr = _try_cast(data, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 754, in _try_cast
    subarr = maybe_cast_to_integer_array(arr, dtype)
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 2069, in maybe_cast_to_integer_array
    raise ValueError("Trying to coerce float values to integers")
ValueError: Trying to coerce float values to integers
```

B. For "uint64" conversion I get a TypeError:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=["id"], dtype="uint64")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-65933034c7a7>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=["id"], dtype="uint64")
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 711, in __init__
    mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 313, in ndarray_to_mgr
    values = sanitize_array(
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 545, in sanitize_array
    subarr = _try_cast(data, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 754, in _try_cast
    subarr = maybe_cast_to_integer_array(arr, dtype)
  File "E:\SOFTWARE\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 2059, in maybe_cast_to_integer_array
    if is_unsigned_integer_dtype(dtype) and (arr < 0).any():
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

What's happening here? Why does float conversion work but not the integer conversion? This is not affected by the size/length of the list nor the elements in it.